# Would it be possible to give 10 minutes warning to people writing answers that the question will be closed or made duplicate in less than 10 minutes?

Tags: feature-request, duplicates, close

I had spent some time answering [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/542878/charge-density-of-a-point-charge?noredirect=1#comment1227843_542878), when it was made duplicate by an announcement at the top "this question will no longer be accepting answers".

Would it not be possible to give ten minutes grace for people who are in the process of writing an answer? "in ten minutes this question will not be accepting any answers"

Since my answer was not an answer to the duplicate question (where I would have transferred it, as I have often done), but an expansion on the way singularities are handled in mainstream physics, I also took some time making it into four comments so that the OP could see the depth of the question's answers in physics, not just mathematics.

My four comments were also removed as saying there should be no answer in comments!! Catch 22.

Comment: As https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/263383 shows, this would probably be technically possible, but I'm unconvinced it's a good idea. If the question is closed for any reason other than being a duplicate, then the question is off-topic and we do not want users to answer it at all. If it's closed as a duplicate and you feel the answer you wanted to give to it does not fit as an answer to the duplicate, then that would be a sign that the two questions are not duplicate and you should vote to reopen..

Comment: @ACuriousMind  Moderators are not the Pope, and  often it is questions from young students  which are closed. An answer that illuminates some physics to the student should not be a problem for the objectives of the site, particularly as closed questions are not seen in search engines, and might help a student  find his/her way into the intricacies of mainstream physics.  Also think: if the moderator had seen the question ten minutes later, the answer would be there, in the closed question.

Comment: @annav Questions are closed based on the question themselves, not the types of answers the question might receive. The closure of a question is not an indication of the quality, utility, etc. of potential answers.

Comment: @AaronStevens  I am talkng of spending some time in composing an answer to an open question up to the minute  I am writing and then I cannot post the answer. I am asking for 10 minutes grace to the closure , which is the same delay in closure as if the moderator had looked and decided 10 minute later.

Comment: @annav Sorry, I was responding to your comment to ACM

Comment: Another case for [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) (initially submitting a one-sentence answer and then extend/revise it in many revisions).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't think that should be done, as stated in [DavidZ's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/542878/charge-density-of-a-point-charge?noredirect=1#comment1227843_542878)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have done that when I suspect the question will be closed, but it is not really within the rules, thats why I am asking this as "feature request"

Comment: I just found out that closed questions appear in searches . I found this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34245/ , searching "why neutrons are heavier than protons"

Comment: Just to give some context to the comment that @Aaron linked: in that particular case, I was talking about posting a non-answer just to get a post in before the question gets closed, and then editing it to turn it into a valid answer later. That's abuse of the system. But if the initial post is a short but legitimate answer to the question, and then you expand on it later, that's okay. (I wouldn't like to see people make a habit of it, but it's allowed.) But you have to be prepared for other people to vote on the initial version of the answer without regard for any future edits you might make.

Comment: @DavidZ I thought you were talking about making a non-answer and then deleting it, and then undeleting after you edit it to be an actual answer. I've seen various high-rep users do this from time to time.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, well that's not specifically what I had in mind, but if it's done to get around the closure of a question, I would also consider that abuse of the system just as if the answer had not been deleted and undeleted. If the question doesn't get closed, I suppose it's not a great practice but it wouldn't really be causing any harm.

Comment: @DavidZ Is there anything users should do if they see this happening? Just flag?

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, I think just flag. I can't think of anything else that really makes sense, unless you want to take it on yourself to ask the person not to do that, but I think the mods can handle that. We can track it, too, so that we're not excessively bugging people who do this only once or twice and we only address it if it becomes a pattern.

Comment: So you accepted an answer just telling you what you wanted to hear rather than an answer actually telling you how you should actually use the site and understand its policies and procedures?

Comment: @AaronStevens I was not asking to understand policies and procedures, I was making a "feature request" , look at the tags, it was the only one I chose but somebody added others. The question I accepted informed me that the feature is inherent in the build up of the site, and showed how to use it.  That in  my, maybe limited understanding,  is a sufficient answer.

Comment: Just to note it, I removed my answer based on arguments that the 4-hour grace-period may've been intended for rare usage, perhaps colored by historical factors.  Regardless, I'm still of the opinion that posters such as yourself, who have a long track-record of making positive contributions, ought to be able to post such positive content irrespective of race conditions.  It does seem wrong that you, acting in good faith, could start writing a good answer with the intent to contribute to this site only to have a moment's difference in hitting the Submit-button obstructing it.

Comment: @Nat Thank you, because you understood what the question was about.

Comment: @annav When you've [voted to close questions in the past](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1226279) (say, using the non-mainstream reason), was your thought process along the lines of "this question should be closed because answers would be harmful" or more along the lines of "well, if somebody is writing a harmful non-mainstream rant to answer this question, they should still have ten minutes to post it"?

Comment: ... or are you proposing to have the closure time-delayed by ten minutes but to have this only available as a privilege past a certain level of rep? Say, as a 50k privilege, you get to ignore or bend the post-closure rules? (I agree that this would be handy, but it goes in the direction of making the site even more top-loaded than it already is, when we should be going in the opposite direction -- removing barriers to participation, not adding more.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I never vote for closure of naive questions, which are the ones I answer trying to educate. I am just making a feature request . The way it might be implemented is not up to me. Such a feature would make life simpler for me, and I suspect for people who ,after having this happen a number of times, leave for other sites.

Comment: @annav The point is that you're effectively proposing to weaken the question-closure mechanisms (at a time where we already have a problem in that the system isn't getting to close homework and non-mainstream questions before they get harmful answers). I'm interested on whether you just want to weaken other people's close votes (with your votes' effect unchanged, as you never "vote to close naive questions"?) or whether you think the same weakening should apply to you.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think annav just wants a warning that a question will be closed so they can save their hard-worked answer somewhere I guess? I guess the system deletes the typed out work once the question is closed.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I am not navel gazing.. It is a simple request for a feature.

Comment: Seems like there may be some underlying disagreement over the importance of closing questions.  Personally, I see the purpose of this site to be facilitating knowledge; I'd vote-to-close questions which I suspect wouldn't tend to serve this purpose, largely for the purpose of noise reduction.  Of course, should someone else disagree with me and wish to answer it anyway, I'd see absolutely no harm in that; even if I wouldn't personally see much value in that exchange, I'd be happy for the other users who do achieving whatever it is that they'd be after.

Comment: Point being that, if I were to vote-to-close something, I'd do so because I'd suspect that the question wouldn't really help anyone.  But then if some folks were to contradict a consequential closure, continuing to engage in productive communication despite my vote-to-close.. well, why should I be upset?  If I thought the question was really bad, I could down-vote it; and if I thought the answer(s) were bad, I could down-vote those, too.  I don't really see the point in stopping proven contributors from doing their thing.

Comment: @Nat If the goal were to "facilitate knowledge" without any constraints, then PSE would essentially become a HW help site fairly quickly. Now, I love helping people with HW, but this site is not the place for that. Many users are under the idea that if it is closed on PSE then it must mean those who voted to close the question see no value in the question, and that just isn't true. The specific policies are in place for a reason, and allowing leniency in certain cases for users who want to post answers on questions that do not fit the policies of PSE essentially makes the policies pointless.

Comment: I do see the reason behind a "warning to close" in the sense of saving work. There cases where I know I would have been upset if one of my "hard work", not yet posted answers had been deleted due to a question being closed. But for the most part if a question ends up closed then I know that my answer probably would not have been appropriate in the first place. The only case where I would feel different is a question being closed as a duplicate, as then I could perhaps "save" my work and post it on the duplicate question instead.

Comment: @AaronStevens: Definitely agree that the policies are in place for reasons; further, it's those reasons that matter -- the policies are merely tools.  The divisive issue here might be applying policies differently to different people; it can feel unfair to those who get more restricted without understanding why, but the underlying reasons can be better served by differential policies.  This motivates stuff like why newbies can't cast [up/down/close/delete]-votes, etc..  And it's why many extra features are knowledge-locked.

Comment: @annav I am asking you to consider the implications of the feature you're proposing beyond the narrow experience you've just had. Here's two easily foreseeable effects with a higher incidence rate: (i) if a new user is providing a bad answer to a bad homework question, they get prompted that the question is about to close, so they post a half-finished answer that's even worse than they would have otherwise, and the site is worse for it. (ii) Ditto with a non-mainstream rant to a non-mainstream question, except now the answerer feels threatened by the site and gets combative.

Comment: Are those widespread problems really worth causing just to save you, and a handful of users who occasionally have your problem from today, the inconvenience of having to come to meta and argue that the question they wanted to answer was wrongly closed?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  for 1) one can edit/finish a posted question, so this is not important. for 2)rants can  be flagged and are deleted by he moderators.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. The trouble to introduce in the programs the feature is minimal. Nobody *has* to come to Meta. I have not come to argue, but to propose a feature that the powers that be may consider. If arguments start, so be it.

Comment: It seems you've missed basically all the points I've made, or you just don't want to consider them. It's a pretty selfish standpoint if you ask me, but that's your prerogative.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Have you considered that everybody's standpoint is selfish? i.e. all people defend their standpoint, as you do. I just do not consider that this change will create a problem , the way that the ability to edit questions and answers is always open does not creat a problem. In some sites you cannot edit at all any answers, in others you are given 7 days. There is a variety on such decisions and certainly the people who make the rules have a reason behind it. I am suggesting considering another variety for this site.

Comment: You objections are registered, and if somebody with the power to decide thinks like you, the answer will be negative. So be it. I do not have to agree with you.

Answer (score 8):

I really think there is no need to do this. There are essentially three cases here:

1. **You agree the question should be closed, and it's closed as duplicate**. You should just answer the duplicate. If your answer fits the closed question but not the duplicate, then you apparently do not agree the question should be closed, go to case 3.
2. **You agree the question should be closed, and it's closed for any other reason**. You just shouldn't have tried to answer it in the first place. The reason we close question is to *prevent them from being answered*, because for one reason or another we do not wish to encourage more of these questions. If you really want to answer this question and think it would be good to have the answer to it on your site, then, again, you apparently do not agree it should be closed. Go to case 3.
3. **You do not agree the question should be closed.** Just vote to reopen.

In neither case is there any substantial benefit offered by allowing answers after closure that I could see. Either you agree the question should be closed and not answer it, or you should vote to reopen it and answer it after it gets reopened. If it stays close because no other reviewers agree it should be reopened, well, that's the nature of the voting system, and it would defeat the purpose of being able to close questions by vote if then individual dissenters could just choose to ignore the closure.

Comment: I am not asking to have answers after closure, I am asking for some respect to somebody who has spent some time answering a question by delaying by 10 minutes the closure to give warning. The "after" is only 10 minutes from an arbitrary time 0 dependent on what time the moderator woke up.!

Comment: @annav Allowing answers for 10 minutes after closure isn't much different functionally from delaying the closure 10 minutes.  I don't see how these answers wouldn't apply regardless.

Comment: @JMac    Maybe it is my greek to english. I am asking not to show the closure on the question until ten minutes have passed from the decision of the moderator to close.

Comment: @annav Closing isn't just a moderator decision.  It's often done by the members with the closure privilege.  Do you want this rule just for single vote closures from moderators/gold badge users?   You're talking about just not showing the closure, you're talking about having the system act as if it's _practically_ not closed for 10 minutes, because people could still answer.

Comment: @JMac  Not open for everybody, just for drafts in progress. If the program can find me to say"no more asnwers accepted" it "kmows" there is an answer in progress.

Comment: @annav Then I would say this answer does a good job explaining why that isn't really a good system.